# tmux new window with current_pane_path always goes to root

Tags: tmux

I have the following config

```
bind-key -n M-c new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}" \;
```

Now, when i invoke this command, it creates a new window but it goes to root director `\`. 
I am running `tmux 1.8`.

Also, in a pane, if i run the following command, it displays the `PWD` correctly.

```
display-message "pwd #{pane_current_path}"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but the `-c ` option is only supported in `tmux` 1.9 and onward